# Does SQL Server use multiversion concurrency control (MVCC)?

Tags: sql-server, mvcc

Reading an older overview of CouchDB published on the IBM site [HERE](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-couchdb/index.html), I was surprised to find the following:

> Most modern databases have started to move from locking mechanisms to
>   MVCC, including Oracle (since V7), MySQL (when used with InnoDB) and
>   Microsoft® SQL Server 2005 and later.

I am using SQL Server quite a bit at the moment (V2012) and never considered that there may be any form of MVCC. I have also used `with (tablock, holdlock)` in stored procedures before.

Does SQL Server really implement MVCC anywhere and how does that reconcile with the idea of `with (tablock, holdlock)` if it does?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Does SQL Server really implement MVCC anywhere

Yes, since SQL Server 2005.

The SQL Server terminology is "row-versioning isolation levels". See the product documentation tree starting at [Locking and Row Versioning](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187101.aspx). Note in particular that there are two separate "MVCC" implementations, *read committed isolation using row versioning* (RCSI) and *snapshot isolation* (SI).

> and how does that reconcile with the idea of `with (tablock, holdlock)` if it does?

Using that combination of hints serializes access to whole table(s). It is the least concurrent option available, so using these hints should be very rare. Whether a particular use could be replaced with RCSI or SI isolation depends on the specific circumstances. You could ask a follow-up question with a specific example if you want us to address that aspect in detail.

You might also like to read my [series of articles](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/07/t-sql-queries/isolation-levels) on SQL Server isolation levels.

Comment: Some analysis on SQL Server from 2020 on how it seems to still not have full MVCC: https://blog.dbi-services.com/how-sql-server-mvcc-compares-to-oracle-and-postgresql/

Comment: @RobGrant That's [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide#behavior-when-modifying-data) behaviour for RCSI to avoid lost updates. I [cover it](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/data-modifications-under-rcsi) in my linked series. The author did not check the SI isolation level (SQL Server's other 'MVCC' option).

Comment: Terminology is confusing adding this for completeness https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/row-versioning-concurrency-in-sql-server/